# How does JSXGraph add hover effect?

Tags: jsxgraph

everyone! I am new to `jsxgraph`, and I would like to know how does JSXGraph add all the hover effect to many elements? Since I can't find any class changed or mouseover event on, for example, the function graph(path element in `svg`, the slider baseline which turn grey when hover...), and I didn't find what I want in the src folder...

Also how to change those effect? are those something to do with highlightCssStyle?

Thank you for reading my question:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSXGraph implements its own hover algorithm. For this, all elements come with the method `hasPoint(x, y)`, where [x,y] are the coordinates of mouse / pen / finger position in pixel. JSXGraph does not use the hover event from SVG, because we also enable highlighting if the pointer device is close to the element (e.g. on touch screens), see the attribute `precision`.

The appearance of highlighting can be controlled by the following attributes:

- highlightStrokeWidth
- highlightStrokeColor
- highlightStrokeOpacity
- highlightFillColor
- highlightFillOpacity
- highlightCSSClass: text / image
- highlightCssDefaultStyle: text
- highlightCssStyle: text

Further, there is the attribute `transitionDuration` which controls the time interval for the transition from default appearance to highlighting and back (in msec).

You can either change the attributes globally:

- JXG.Options.line.highlightStrokeWidth = 5;

or per element:
var li = board.create('line', [...], {highlightStrokeWidth: 5});

Further, you can find the default CSS styles for image and texts in jsxgraph.css

Comment: Thank you for the quick and helpful answer!
Just ask out of curious, is it possible to clone a node, set a wider stroke-width and mouseenter listener on it to serve as a hover algorithm?

Comment: Hi @YwL, if you find the answer useful it would be nice if you upvote it. It helps the community and the user who helped you.